# counting a text string in non-consecutive sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel 2003
I`ve a question about counting a text string *Man* in sheets named 001R through 900R, in the same cell C8 of all the sheets

I`ve got the following answer

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&ROW(INDIRECT(001&":"&900))&"R"&"'!C8"),"*Man*"))`

This works perfectly when the sheets are all present. But when using the above formula when not all the sheets are present yet, it gives an error, because I have worksheet names as

`001R` `002R` `003S` `004R` `101R` `102S` `103R` `210R` `211R` `305R` `306S` `307R` `401R` `402R` `403S` `404R`

and so on for some 300 sheets, and the missing sheet numbers will be added later on as their data will be available.

Is there a way to use a formula that spans all the numbers to include the present and possible future sheet names, to avoid editing the formula each time a new sheet is added?

@Gary's Student has a very helpful answer.
But I want to count the text in a dropdown list with many items, and I want to count the occurrence of each one.
With your technique, should I make a UDF module for each item; or is there a way to make this.

Also, I have sheets with S not R attached to their number. Is there a way to count those too?
I mean is there a way to make

```
shName = Format(i, "000") & "R"
```

and

```
If InStr(1, cel, "Man") as variables entered in =SpecialSum(C8).
```

Comment: what was your original question? a link to that would help to understand your current one.

Comment: Can I ask why: a) You are "cross-posting" this post on more than one forum? b) You have yet to respond to an outstanding reply made to you at another forum from 5 days ago: (http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/912915-counting-text-non-consecutive-sheets.html)?

Comment: @Hany0 ,did you create two accounts ? [Merge them](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

The following User Defined Function will examine your block of worksheets.  If the sheet exists, then the cell of interest is examined to see if it **contains** the string *Man*.  If the string is present, the count is incremented:

```
Public Function SpecialSum(rin As Range) As Long
   Dim addy As String, i As Long, shName As String
   Dim cel As String
   Application.Volatile

   addy = rin.Address

   For i = 1 To 900
      shName = Format(i, "000") & "R"
      On Error Resume Next
         cel = Sheets(shName).Range(addy).Text
         If Err.Number = 0 Then
            If InStr(1, cel, "Man") > 0 Then SpecialSum = SpecialSum + 1
         Else
            Err.Number = 0
         End If
      On Error GoTo 0
   Next i

End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=SpecialSum(C8)
```

where **C8** is the cell of interest.  To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

This will allow you to add/remove worksheets without editing the formula.