# counting text in non-consecutive sheets with variables

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel 2003, I've posted a question about counting text in 
[1](https://superuser.com/questions/1025655/counting-a-text-string-in-non-consecutive-sheets/1026602#1026602)
I got a very helpful answer by Gary's Student.

But I want to count the text in a dropdown list with many items, and I want to count the occurrence of each one.
With Gary's Student technique, should I make a UDF module for each item; or is there a way to make this.
Also, I have sheets with S not R attached to their number. Is there a way to count those too separately?
I mean is there a way to make
shName = Format(i, "000") & "R"
and
If InStr(1, cel, "Man")
as variables entered in =SpecialSum(C8).

Comment: Rather than making another question, you can add comments to his question and ask him directly. Don't forget to upvote or accept his answer if it helps you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an extension of an answer to another question (http://superuser.com/questions/1025655/counting-a-text-string-in-non-consecutive-sheets/1026602#1026602)

Comment: I added this question as a comment, but I got a message
A moderator has deleted this post

Comment: **.....Jonno's comment is valid....** Lets update the **original Post.**